Kusto - fetch data from one table where matching records do not exist in another table
I have two tables in azure data explorer db, first table is Users and the second one is Heartbeat. Users table has certain fields including email. Heartbeat table has email and Heartbeat send date/time column.
I need to select all the users who are NOT sending heartbeat between a time range.
I am using the following query but it doesn't return the records.
Users
| join kind=leftouter Heartbeat on $left.userEmail == $right.userEmail
| where userEmail1 !has (userEmail)
| where HeartBeatDate between (datetime('2024-07-14 16:04:10')..datetime('2024-07-15 16:04:10'))
| distinct userLoginName,userEmail,userFullName,userPicture,userCreateDate,userPhoneNumber

If I remove where clause of date/time range I get the data but I need to filter and search only between the given time range.
Thanks.

In order to get the user details who did not send their heartbeat details within the specified time zone, you can modify your code as below,
Heartbeat
| where HeartBeatDate between (datetime('2024-07-14 16:04:10')..datetime('2024-07-15 16:04:10')) //give the timezone here
| distinct userEmail
| join kind=rightouter (Users) on $left.userEmail == $right.userEmail
| where isempty(userEmail)
| project-away userEmail

demo
This query first filters the  Heartbeat  table to include only the rows where the  HeartBeatDate  is within the specified range. It then selects the distinct  userEmail  values from the  Heartbeat  table. These values are then used to perform a  rightouter  join with the  Users  table. The result of join includes all the rows from the  Users  table and only the matching rows from the  Heartbeat  table. The  where  clause filters out all the rows where there is a matching row in the  Heartbeat  table (i.e., where  userEmail  is not  null). Finally, the  project-away  operator is used to remove the duplicate  userEmail  column from the output.
Edit:

Heartbeat
| where HeartBeatDate between (datetime('2022-01-01 16:04:10')..datetime('2022-01-03 16:04:10'))//give the timezone here
| distinct userEmail 
| join kind=rightouter (Users) on  $left.userEmail == $right.userEmail
| where isempty(userEmail)
| project-away userEmail
| join kind=leftouter (Geolocation) on $left.userEmail1 == $right.userEmail
| where isempty(userEmail)
| project-away userEmail1


Thanks Aswin, it works perfect.
I have another table called Geolocation with the same email field and now I need to fetch all users who exist in heartbeat but NOT in Geolocation within a specified time range in heartbeat table. How can I modify the above query?

Replace heartbeat table with Geoplocation

Actually here three tables are involved. Users -> from where user data will be selected. Heartbeat -> Users should exist in heartbeat between the given time range. Geolocation -> Users should NOT exist in this table

Can you ask another detailed question with this requirement. Provide sample data also, with expected output.

Actually I can't post new questions for a few days. The only difference between this question and the new question is before I needed users who do not exist in heartbeat. Now I need users who exist in heartbeat but do not exist in geolocation.

Edited the answer. Check that once

Thanks Aswin, one more question. How can we edit the query to skip the records that fall between 2am and 6am?

What is the field name that consists of time details?
